# output keeps only using place holder 0 in python

Tags: python

```
how_many = int(input("How many people are playing?: "))
counter = 0
player = 0
while counter < how_many:
    print("Player", counter, "name: ")
    input(player)
    print("Hi", player, "What are you bringing to the picnic?")
    counter = counter+1
```

My code is outputting "Hi 0 what are you bringing to the picnic" but I need it to say "hi (name user inputted) What are you bringing to the picnic?"

Comment: Why don't you use the same technique you used for `how_many` also for `player`?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get user input from std in python is `player = input()`

```
how_many = int(input("How many people are playing?: "))
counter = 0
player = 0
while counter < how_many:
    print("Player", counter, "name: ")
    player = input()
    print("Hi", player, "What are you bringing to the picnic?")
    counter = counter+1
```

Comment: That did it, thanks man

Comment: @QuinnWillett please upvote and mark it as answer. Thanks